# Javascript create a timed onClick event handler that doesn't freeze the page?

Tags: javascript, html

Goal: Have a button that when clicked greys out for 1 second and after the second increments a value. This should allow you to do other actions on the page while waiting.

Issue: When I click the button the page freezes and I must wait until the wait function has completed before I can click another button. Also the button doesn't grey out. It stops its animation and then completes it once the 1 second has passed.

HTML Code:

```
<button id=woodBtn class=woodBtnC type="button" onClick="getWood()">Get Wood</button> 
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Wood</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id=woodValue>0</td>>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function getWood() {
    wood++;
    greyOut("woodBtn", 1);
    document.getElementById("woodValue").innerHTML = wood;
    writeConsole("Got 1 wood!!");
}

function greyOut(id, time) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = "0.5";
    var start = Date.now();
    do{
        var now = Date.now();
        var delta = now - start;
    } while (delta < 1000);
    document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = "1.0";
}
```

I don't think javascript has threading, so I how do I do this without them?

Comment: Have a look at [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `greyOut` code with:

```js
function greyOut(id, time) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = "0.5";
    var start = Date.now();
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = "1.0";
    }, 1000) // delay time ms
}
```

It should work

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much I was totally lost. I'll need to look into why this way works but the other doesn't.

Comment: Cool, I recommend you to read about event loop and timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

JS is a single threaded language, so all the code runs on one thread only - You cannot do multi processing. You are consuming the thread fully for 1 second when you are waiting for 1 second due a continuous loop - that loop might be running millions of times before terminating and the whole page would freeze because it is running incessantly and JS can't do anything else. The way to handle such cases is to use event loop and callback function - JS will tell someone to hold a function till specified event occurs and when that event occurs, that someone will give that function back to JS to run. In this case that someone is browser, the browser provides an API `setTimeout` which runs a function after specified time. Here is the code:

```js
var wood = 0;

function getWood() {
  wood++;
  // greyOut("woodBtn", 1);
  asyncGreyOut("woodBtn", 1000, function() {
    document.getElementById("woodValue").innerHTML = wood;
    // writeConsole("Got 1 wood!!");
    console.log("Got 1 wood!!");
  });
}

function asyncGreyOut(id, time, cb) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = "0.5";
  setTimeout(function() {
    cb();
    document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = "1.0";
  }, time);
}

function greyOut(id, time) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = "0.5";
  var start = Date.now();
  do {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - start;
  } while (delta < 1000);
  document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = "1.0";
}
```

```html
<button id=woodBtn class=woodBtnC type="button" onClick="getWood()">
  Get Wood
</button>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Wood</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="woodValue">0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```